# How do I prepare data which has a trend for use in a Copula model?

Tags: time-series, random-variable, trend, copula

I want to use a set of daily water quality data including 3 parameters in a Copula model.  Somebody told me these data do not have a condition of a random variable to use in copula, and I should do some work on it (my guess is that it involves detrending the data).

Can anybody help me in finding methods to prepare the data to use in a copula method? I would appreciate if you can refer me to good journal papers or books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copulas are used for constructing joint distributions given the marginals.  The parameters of the copula are used to model dependencies(correlation) between the marginals.

A good manuscript describing copulas is

http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~tschmidt/TSchmidt_Copulas.pdf

Unless you have some reason for transforming the observations from the marginals (maybe scaling or translating them), you do not need to "prepare" them to model them using a copula but maybe you have to take some time to choose properly the corresponding marginal distributions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but my data is a daily water quality data and it it has trend and seasonality therefore it can not be used directly in a copula model. I am sure about that because an expert told me that it is not a random data (I guess it is because that for different days of a year it has a trend). I want to know how can I prepare it to use in the model (I know it can be done by time series analysis and residuals but I don't know how).

Comment: If the data are not random (according to that expert), then you cannot assign a stochastic model.  My guess is that you need a different thing. Something like a nonlinear regression model or a time series. But more information about your data would help.

Comment: I attached the graph of my data (daily values of DO and T for 365 days of the year) in this link http://tinypic.com/r/2elyqrm/6

Comment: Regarding the second plot, it looks like a "seasonal trend" with a small variability between two consecutive days. Which is something expected but you can observe some small "noise". See for example the following simulation in R `plot(25*sin(seq(1,365,1)*pi/365)+rnorm(365,0,1))`. In the first plot the variability between two consecutive days is more apparent. Again, my guess is that what you need here is a nonlinear model that accounts for seasonality and other features present in your context. However, I do think that the data can be treated as random.